# git shasum and node sha1 do not produce the same hashe

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, md5, sha

```
$ echo -e 'blob 14\0Hello, World!' | shasum
```

produces: `8ab686eafeb1f44702738c8b0f24f2567c36da6d`

running this in js/node:

```
var sha1 = require('sha1');

const fileContents = "Hello, World!";
const length = fileContents.length + 1;

const blobString = `blob ${length}\0${fileContents}`;

const hash = sha1(blobString);

console.log(blobString);
console.log(hash);
```

produces:

```
blob 14Hello, World!
d4fcfe4d339d4e59d168fdf3c0ad445fa980a7d6
```

why are the hashes not equal ? (`8ab686eafeb1f44702738c8b0f24f2567c36da6d != d4fcfe4d339d4e59d168fdf3c0ad445fa980a7d6`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hashes are not equal because of the difference of a newline character in the input.
`echo` adds a newline. Use `printf` instead:

```
printf 'blob 14\0Hello, World!' | shasum
# prints: d4fcfe4d339d4e59d168fdf3c0ad445fa980a7d6
```

This works too, but not as portable, because the flags of `echo` are not supported predictably in all systems:

```
echo -ne 'blob 14\0Hello, World!' | shasum
```